# Emscripten: algorithm.h file not found

Tags: c++, algorithm, std, emscripten

I am trying to compile the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <algorithm.h>

int main() {
  printf("hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

But when I run `emcc test.c -o test.html` I get the following error:

```
fatal error: 'algorithm.h' file not found
```

When I remove the line that imports `algorithm.h` the code compiles perfectly.

Why is this happening? I was under the impression that `algorithm.h` was part of the standard library.

Edit:

I changed the name of the file from `test.c` to `test.cpp`, I updated the header names to `<cstdio>` and `<algorithms>`, and I also set `-std=c++11` and it works now.

Comment: You have the `c++` tag but this looks suspiciously like C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is C++ use

```
#include <cstdio>
```

in place of `stdio.h` and

```
#include <algorithm>
```

instead

Answer (score 2):

In *standard* C++ there is no `<algorithm.h>` - there is only `<algorithm>`

Also in C++ the stdio header is both accessible from `<cstdio>` and `<stdio.h>` for compatibility.

Also since you are including algorithm the file extension should be `.cc` or `.cpp` and not `.c` or else emcc/gcc will treat it as a C source instead of a C++ one.